# Deleting dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I am a beginner in C++ and I have a doubt. If I have a code like this:

```
int* f(int n){               //global

int* arr = new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
arr[i]=i;

return arr;
}

void main() {

int n;
scanf("%d",&n);


int* arr1 = new int;  //or should I write just int* arr1; ?
arr1 = f(n);

delete [] arr1;  // or just delete arr1;
}
```

The question is should I delete arr1 as array or not since I declared it as pointer to int?
The code doesn't make much sense but it is good as an example. I know there are a lot of similar question but I could not find the exact answer to my question.

Comment: Neither. You should use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: I know but it is requested by my professor to use pointers in the beginning.

Comment: That's pretty silly class design. That's like starting an architecture class by designing a suspension bridge before moving on to a bikeshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the allocation was made with `new <type>[n]` then the deallocation must be made with `delete []`.

All that counts when determining the correct form of `delete` is the form of `new` that was used in the allocation.

In your `main` function, you leak memory. You initialize `arr1` with a call to `new` and then immediately overwrite that value with the new pointer returned by the call to `f()`. The call to `new` from `main` is simply wrong and should be removed. Write it simply like this:

```
int* arr1 = f(n);
```

And your `main` should be

```
int main()
```

Comment: So I should use delete arr1 because I allocated arr1 with new (not new [])?

Comment: No. You allocated arr1 with new[]

Comment: int* arr1 = new int;
but arr is with new[] in the f(int)

Comment: As I said, remove that line which just leaks. One call to new int[n] and one matching delete[] is what you need. Do you see why your code leaks?

Comment: @stefaneli31 Whether to use `delete` or `delete[]` does not depend on the pointer you declared but more on what the pointer points to. In your example `arr1` first points to one single `int` (`new int` allocates exactly one `int`) so you have to call `delete arr1;`. After the function call `arr1 = f(n);` `arr1` points to an array of `int`s so you have to use `delete[] arr1;`.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
int* arr1 = f(n);
```

and later

```
delete[] arr1;
```

the array object is allocated in `f()`, and `delete` deletes it. The pointer itself can not be deleted, just the object(array) it points to.